# Update all subcategory (upto N-level) of a category from Root

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have below structure of the table, which is mimicking a folder hierarchy in FileExplorer (Just like category-subcategory). Now my requirement is to update all children of a root folder (up to N-level) by copying root container id (to all sub-folders of the root).

[image]

I know how to update up to a single level but can't generalize UPDATE statement to affect upto n-levels. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm able to achieve required result. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to achieve desired result using CTE. Below is code snippet which I used to achieve the required outcome

```
;WITH MyCTE
AS ( SELECT FolderId, FolderName, ParentFolderId, FK_ContainerId [RootContainerId], 
FK_ContainerId
FROM tblFC_Folders
WHERE ParentFolderId IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT t.FolderId, t.FolderName, t.ParentFolderId, MyCTE.[RootContainerId] AS 
[RootContainerId], t.FK_ContainerId
FROM tblFC_Folders t
INNER JOIN MyCTE ON t.ParentFolderId = MyCTE.FolderId
WHERE t.ParentFolderId IS NOT NULL )
UPDATE  tblFC_Folders
SET  FK_ContainerId = MyCTE.RootContainerId
FROM tblFC_Folders t INNER JOIN MyCTE ON t.FolderId = MyCTE.FolderId
WHERE t.ParentFolderId IS NOT NULL AND t.FK_ContainerId IS NULL
```